# FlatList not working but map is working. I don't know why

Tags: javascript, react-native

Data(feelings) is array.

```js
// this code not working
<FlatList
    data={feelings}
    keyExtractor={(feelings) => feelings._id}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
        console.log(item);
        return (
            <View>
              <Text>{item.message}</Text>
            </View>
        );
      }}
    />

// this code working
{feelings.map((item) => (
    <View>
        <Text>{item.message}</Text>
    </View>
  ))}

// also when I change data like this it works too
<FlatList
    data={[{message:'11'},{message:'22'}]}
    keyExtractor={(feelings) => feelings._id}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
        console.log(item);
        return (
            <View>
              <Text>{item.message}</Text>
            </View>
        );
      }}
    />
```

I don't know why this happening.
Im using M1 MacBook Air

I tried to change FlatList data to [{message:'11'},{message:'22'}] and it's working. (third code)

but not working with feelings data

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I guess feelings data is array inside of array. So I use map and flat to solve problem.

```
data = {feelings} -> data = {feelings.map((feeling)=>feeling).flat()}
```

I hope this answer can help anyone who had same issue like me.